# Reading from multiple dynamic locations in Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, jbossfuse, consumer

I have a batch job in which I'm expected to download file from multiple locations in Apache Camel.

I'm using following strategy to complete this process.

- Start route on a `quartz2` schedule
- Retrieve list of endpoints to download files (This can be either sftp locations or simply file locations)
- For each file in list,
- Download file
- Save in destination.

So, the problem is with downloading file. As per my knowledge, there is no way to consume file in middle of a camel route.

There is **Enrich** EIP. But I can't use it as file locations are dynamic and **Enrich** does not support dynamic files names till version camel version 2.16. For some reasons, I'm expected to stick with version 2.15.1...redhat..

So, to overcome this issue, I have written a custom processor for downloading the file. Following is my code for custom processor.

```
public class DynamicConsumer implements Processor{

@Override
public void process(Exchange inExchange) throws Exception {
    CamelContext camelContext = inExchange.getContext();
    ConsumerTemplate consumerTemplate = camelContext.createConsumerTemplate();
    String resource = inExchange.getProperty("RESOURCE", String.class);

    consumerTemplate.start();
    Exchange resourceExchange = consumerTemplate.receive(resource);
    consumerTemplate.stop();

    inExchange.getOut().setBody(resourceExchange.getIn().getBody());
    inExchange.getProperties().putAll(resourceExchange.getProperties());
    inExchange.getOut().getHeaders().putAll(resourceExchange.getIn().getHeaders());
}

}
```

This custom processor is downloading files as expected. But the problem is, it is not deleting **Camel Lock** after downloading the file.

So, I would like to know

- Whether I'm using custom processor in the right way?
- Why camel is not removing the file lock after downloading/reading the file

Comment: You probably already know this, but JBoss Fuse includes Camel 2.17.0

Comment: In my question, I have mentioned that, I need to keep version 2.15.1.